# cmake error while exporting iOS project : iphoneos is not an iOS SDK

Tags: cmake, cocos2d-x

I executed the below command in terminal to export Xcode Project

```
cmake .. -GXcode -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=iOS -DCMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT=iphoneos
```

However, I am getting this error:

> CMake Error : iphoneos is not an iOS SDK...Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Found solution [Here](https://github.com/leetal/ios-cmake/issues/52)

In Terminal, execute:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```